# Jersey + Embedded Jetty Redirect With HTTP 200 Code

Tags: java, jersey, embedded-jetty, redirect

I'm using Jersey at my embedded Jetty application. I have a redirection as like that:

```
URI uri = URI.create(url);
return Response.seeOther(uri).build();
```

seeOther is like that:

```
public static ResponseBuilder seeOther(URI location) {
    ResponseBuilder b = status(Status.SEE_OTHER).location(location);
    return b;
}
```

However that redirection has a 303 code as well. If I explicitly set location and pass 200 OK it does not redirect.

How can I redirect the page while I have 200 OK status?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is the expected behaviour of a http redirect to send [303](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303),

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Statuses 301/302/303/307 ARE the http way of signaling redirects to a client.

The mechanism is as follows:

1. Client accesses a resource on server
2. Server responds with status 307 and location: header pointing to redirection target
3. Client accesses URI provided by location: header.
4. This time, the server usually returns the desired content with a status 200. But that is not what your code is about.

If you leave out the 307 (or 301/302/303) statuscode, the client will simply not understand what it's supposed to do with the location: header.

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html for details on expected behaviour with regard to statuscodes - you will probably also find 301 (MOVED) or 307 (TEMPORARY_REDIRECT) cover most scenarios. 303's (SEE_OTHER) are rare in my experience.